# Does AWS CloudFormation support Tags Property Attribute for AWS::EC2::VPCEndpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, tags, aws-cloudformation, key-value, vpc

I have been trying to create endpoints for my two vpc's, it is creating the vpc's, but it is not working with the Tags property which i require to name the vpc endpoint created.

> Error: "Encountered unsupported property Tags"

```
{
  "Resources": {
        "VPCEndpoint1": {
            "Type" : "AWS::EC2::VPCEndpoint",
            "Properties" : {
                "PrivateDnsEnabled" : "True",
                "RouteTableIds" : ["rtb-1"],
                "ServiceName" : "com.amazonaws.eu-west-1.s3",
                "VpcEndpointType" : "Gateway",
                "VpcId" : "vpc-id1",
                "Tags": [
                    {
                        "Key": "Name",
                        "Value": "name1"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "VPCEndpoint2": {
            "Type" : "AWS::EC2::VPCEndpoint",
            "Properties" : {
                "PrivateDnsEnabled" : "True",
                "RouteTableIds" : ["rtb-2"],
                "ServiceName" : "com.amazonaws.eu-west-1.s3",
                "VpcEndpointType" : "Gateway",
                "VpcId" : "vpc-id2",
                "Tags": [
                    {
                        "Key": "Name",
                        "Value": "name2"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Feature request here: https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/aws-cloudformation-coverage-roadmap/issues/196

Answer (score 1):

Cloudformation do not support Tags property.

Refer cloudformation document => https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-vpcendpoint.html

Answer (score 1):

Tags are supported for AWS::EC2::VPC, But not for AWS::EC2::VPCEndpoint.

If, you need tags, create tags on vpc level, not on endpoints.

VPC Level Tags - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-vpc.html

Comment: I have created the vpc's and added tags. That do work. But what if i need to name the endpoint that i'm creating above.

Comment: i need the created vpcendpoint to have a name given by me. i can't leave it nameless

Answer (score 0):

### CloudFormation does not support tagging VPC Endpoints yet.

See https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cloudformation-coverage-roadmap/issues/196

---

### Here is a workaround to tag your VPCE in CloudFormation:

You can setup the **custom resource** and **macro** from https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cloudformation-templates/tree/55ebf9f7129e87530e68c242d7e46167e6a798b8/aws/services/CloudFormation/MacrosExamples/Boto3

The code is 4 years old, so it needs to be updated:

- Use python3.9
- Move lambda code to `InlineCode` in template to replace `urllib2` with [`cfnresponse`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_en/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-lambda-function-code-cfnresponsemodule.html)
- Remove calls to `json.dumps`
- Remove property case lowering

---

Then you should be able to add a tag using CloudFormation like this:

```yaml
VpceTagName:
  Type: Boto3::ec2.create_tags
  Properties:
    Resources:
      - !Ref VpcEndpoint
    Tags:
      - Key: Name
        Value: My VPCE
```